# Want to save user selection for character throughout application

Tags: java, android

This is my first app, and i have just about zero programming knowledge. However, when the app is opened, the user is asked to choose a character from a scroll view which they will use throughout the rest of the app. How do i get this chosen character to be displayed on other activity screens?

Here is the xml for the choose character activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_choose_pet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mc.cibi.ChoosePet">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Please Choose Your CiBi Pet!"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="522dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

      <!-- <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gifraffe"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:id="@+id/giraffe"
            android:onClick="giraffebtn"/>-->

        <ImageButton
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="300dp"
              android:background="@drawable/goat"
              android:id="@+id/goat"
              android:onClick="goatbtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/monkey"
            android:id="@+id/monkey"
            android:onClick="monkeybtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/moose"
            android:id="@+id/moose"
            android:onClick="moosebtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/owl"
            android:id="@+id/owl"
            android:onClick="owlbtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rhino"
            android:id="@+id/rhino"
            android:onClick="rhinobtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>





</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the user to be able to see the image of their selected image button on future screens in the application. All help is appreciated!

Comment: you can done with the using shared prefernces visit this [link](http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126)

Comment: @PratikMohanraoGondil Shared preferences are ok if he needs this to last between launches, but overkill if he doesn't.  And even if he does, he shouldn't be saving the URL, but saving an identifier for the selection so he can get all the data about the character again, since its unlikely he just needs the name.  Given that, if he does need to let it last between launches he's probably better off serializing to disk than using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you're absolutely new to programming, I'll go into a lot of basic detail here.

Sending data to another activity is easy-  when you create the Intent you use to start it, you add the data as an Extra.

The question then is what to add.  Generally what you'd do to hold data like this is define a class Character.  That class would hold all of the important info about a character-  the name, the image url, etc. It would also have the actions you can take on this character-  maybe a function to change the name, or to set it's parent's name, or to do whatever else you need to do to it.  This technique is called Object Oriented Programming.  You'd generally create an instance of this class for each button.  Then when one of the buttons is pressed, you store off that instance. Later, when you launch the next Activity, you add it to the Intent as I said before.

Remember that to pass a class via Intent, it needs to implement either Parcelable or Serializable.  I'd suggest just using Serializable-  it's a little slower, but the class is small enough to not matter and its much easier to implement (generally you don't need to even override any functions).